# Traspasar elementos de un array a otro

Tags: php

estoy intentando traspasar un array a otro, el primer array tiene los siguientes elementos, los cuales algunos tienen strings separados por espacio coma espacio ( , ):

```
$array = ["200 , 358/E23", "789"]
```

El resultado que quiero sería:

```
$nuevo_array = ["200","358/E23","789"]
```

Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $nuevo_array[] = explode(" , ", $value);                             
}
```

pero el resultado que obtengo es un array de arrays.

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($nuevo_array);
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 358/E23
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 789
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al hacer explode estas cogiendo el elemento y separandolo por lo que has pedido que lo separe, si encuentra eso que buscas te sacara los elementos que son, si no encuentra dejara solo un elemento, pero lo mete dentro de un array. Tu estas cogiendo este array que te devuelve el explode y metiendolo dentro de otro array, por eso tienes un array con dos arrays.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como dejarlo todo al mismo nivel:

```php
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $elements = explode(" , ", $value);

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $nuevo_array[] = $element;
    }
}
```

Comment: Buen día, recuerda que una buena respuesta contiene explicación del código

Comment: Buen día, gracias por tu respuesta adrigo, es lo que necesitaba.